# LoopbackJS register model for unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, loopbackjs

I want to unit test a mixin.
So I need to create a loopback 3.x application completely in code.
It works so far and it registers my mixin, but it doesn't register my model.
It is not exposed over REST, but thats exactly what I need.

Here is my code:

```
// create loopback app
app = loopback();

app.use(loopback.rest());

// create data source
app.dataSource('db', {
    name: 'db',
    connector: loopback.Memory
});

app.loopback.modelBuilder.mixins.define('accesscheck', AccessCheck);

app.loopback.createModel({ 
    name: 'AccesscheckTest',
    plural: 'AccesscheckTests',
    base: "PersistedModel",
    accesscheck: [{
        permission: "ALLOW",
        roles: [
            'admin'
        ],
        accessScope: "organization",
        method: "findById"
    }],
    mixins: [
        "accesscheck"
    ]
});

var Accesscheck = app.loopback.getModel('Accesscheck');
app.model(Accesscheck, { dataSource: 'db', public: true });

// start server
var connection = app.listen(3000, () => {
    if (done) {
        done();
    }
});

app.activeConnection = connection;

return app;
```

PS: I know that there is the ACL Model in loopback but it doesn't fit my need so I need to implement my own Accesscheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call boot from `loopback-boot`.

I think it's better to require the `server.js` in test units.

And make config file for test in this pattern `datasources.test.json` and a script in `package.json` for test like this : `"test": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --recursive",`

So there is no need to create models in unit tests anymore.

Comment: I think it is pretty much overhead to include a complete loopback project just to test a simple mixin. I want to create a npm package for this mixin so I can reuse it in multiple loopback applications.

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 You told you want to make server and expose over rest. So this is not unit test. And I think it's better to load complete project for integration/acceptance test

Comment: you are absolutely right, since I start a server this are integration tests. I will try it this way and keep the overhead as minimal as possible. Thanks for your help

Comment: @blacksheep_2011 You're welcome. If my answer is right, please kindly accept it.